# Xcode Air print

Tags: swift2

I am a beginner with xcode and swift.

I have a couple of fields and a image in my viewcontroller and I would like to print the content of this fields...

My code from a tutorial:

```
@IBAction func print(sender: AnyObject) {

    // 1

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()

    // 2

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)

    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General

    printInfo.jobName = "Rapport"

    printController.printInfo = printInfo

    // 3

    let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: itemName.text!)

    formatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 72, left: 72, bottom: 72, right: 72)

    printController.printFormatter = formatter

    // 4

    printController.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)


}
```

works very well with this only textfield. But how can I print the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a formatter to send to the `printController` and send him a markup text to print. This function takes a string, so you can create a custom string with all the text you want it to have and call the function, like this:

```
// 3
let myMarkupText = itemName.text! + "\n" + secondField.text! + "\n" + anotherField.text!
let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: myMarkupText)
...
```

I added the "\n" to start a new line, but you can format it the way you want, of course. I'm not sure if "\n" would create a new line anyway (since this is markup, maybe you need `<br />`), you'd have to try and see.

If you wanted to print the whole page instead of just certain parts, you could also check the [documentation for UIPrintInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/index.html) to see what other options you have (`printingItem`, `printingItems`, `printPageRenderer`).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have a long string with multiple \n carriage returns, you need to first replace all of the \n occurrences with br / before submitting the string to the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter.  Here is an example for Swift 4:

```
func print(text: String) {
    let textWithNewCarriageReturns = text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br />")

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.general
    printController.printInfo = printInfo

    let format = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: textWithNewCarriageReturns)

    format.perPageContentInsets.top = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.bottom = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.left = 72
    format.perPageContentInsets.right = 72
    printController.printFormatter = format

    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```